# Is there a way to search 2 or more fields at the same time?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am looking into creating something that does this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`tm_accounts`)
WHERE  CONCAT(`last_name`, `first_name`)  LIKE '%o%'
```

This, of course, doesn't work. I just want you to see the idea behind what I'm trying to emulate.

last_name and first_name are two separate fields in the accounts table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (`tm_accounts`)
WHERE last_name LIKE '%o%' 
   or first_name LIKE '%o%';
```

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM TM_ACCOUNTS a
 WHERE a.first_name LIKE '%o%'
UNION
SELECT b.*
  FROM TM_ACCOUNTS b
 WHERE b.last_name LIKE '%o%'
```

`OR`s are notorious for poor performance, and have maintenance risks.

Mind that I'm using `UNION`, which will remove duplicates from the ultimate resultset.  While `UNION ALL` would perform better, it does not remove duplicates - making it not ideal for use in this case.

In case you weren't aware, putting a wildcard on the lefthand side of your `LIKE` criteria won't use an index.  So if you had an index on `TM_ACCOUNTS.last_name` or `TM_ACCOUNTS.first_name` (or both if using a covering index).

This:

```
WHERE CONCAT(`last_name`, `first_name`)  LIKE '%o%'
```

...isn't a good habit - a better approach is to perform the function in a subselect/inline view.  For example:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CONCAT(t.last_name, t.first_name) AS full_name
          FROM TM_ACCOUNTS t) x
 WHERE x.full_name LIKE '%o%'
```

Comment: Amazing explanation. You have my +1!

Comment: Better, but still not good unless you have no way around it.  On most RDBMSs wrapping columns in a function prevents the use of any indexes on the column(s) so wrapped.

Comment: @Donnie: Index use is moot because of `LIKE '%o` anyways.